# Prove that the recursion is an integer

Tags: number-theory

> A "number triangle" $(t_{n, k})$ $(0 \le k \le n)$ is defined by $t_{n,0} = t_{n,n} = 1$ $(n \ge 0),$
>   $$t_{n+1,m} =(2 -\sqrt{3})^mt_{n,m} +(2 +\sqrt{3})^{n-m+1}t_{n,m-1} \quad (1 \le m \le n).$$
>   Prove that all $t_{n,m}$ are integers.

I created the table below to help see the pattern and the recursion actually seems to be an algorithm for determining what coefficients $C_1,C_2$ make $C_1(2-\sqrt{3})^a+C_2(2+\sqrt{3})^b$ an integer. How can we use the information in the table below to solve the problem?

We make a table:

$t_{0,0} = 1$

$t_{1,0} = 1$

$t_{1,1} = 1$

$t_{2,0} = 1$

$t_{2,1} = (2-\sqrt{3})+(2+\sqrt{3}) = 4$

$t_{2,2} = 1$

$t_{3,0} = 1$

$t_{3,1} = (2-\sqrt{3})t_{2,1}+(2+\sqrt{3})^2 t_{2,0} = 4(2-\sqrt{3})+(2+\sqrt{3})^2 = 15$

$t_{3,2} = (2-\sqrt{3})^2 t_{2,2}+(2+\sqrt{3}) t_{2,1} = (2-\sqrt{3})^2+4(2+\sqrt{3}) = 15$

$t_{3,3} = 1$

$t_{4,0} = 1$

$t_{4,1} = (2-\sqrt{3}) t_{3,1}+(2+\sqrt{3})^3 t_{3,0} = 15(2-\sqrt{3})+(2+\sqrt{3})^3 = 56$

$t_{4,2} = (2-\sqrt{3})^2 t_{3,2}+(2+\sqrt{3})^2t_{3,1}= 15(2-\sqrt{3})^2 +15(2+\sqrt{3})^2 = 210$

$t_{4,3}= (2-\sqrt{3})^3 t_{3,3}+(2+\sqrt{3})t_{3,2} = (2-\sqrt{3})^3+15(2+\sqrt{3}) = 56$

$t_{4,4} = 1$

$t_{5,0} = 1$

$t_{5,1} = (2-\sqrt{3})t_{4,1}+(2+\sqrt{3})^4 t_{4,0} = 56(2-\sqrt{3})+(2+\sqrt{3})^4 = 209$

$t_{5,2} = (2-\sqrt{3})^2 t_{4,2}+(2+\sqrt{3})^4 t_{4,1} = 210(2-\sqrt{3})^2+56(2+\sqrt{3})^3 = 2926$

$t_{5,3} = (2-\sqrt{3})^3 t_{4,3}+(2+\sqrt{3})^2 t_{4,2} = 56(2-\sqrt{3})^3+210(2+\sqrt{3})^2 = 2926$

$t_{5,4} = (2-\sqrt{3})^4 t_{4,4}+(2+\sqrt{3}) t_{4,3} = (2-\sqrt{3})^4+56(2+\sqrt{3})^2 = 209$

$t_{5,5} = 1$

Comment: Did you try induction?  First show for 0,0 (which you have).  Then assume for n,m.  Show for n+1,0.  Then assume for n+1,k and show for for n+1,k+1.  Then you'll be done.

Comment: @fleablood I think it is more complicated than induction because the results holds more than just because $t_{n+1,k}$ is an integer.

Comment: Maybe.  It was just a suggestion.  The proposition might need to be more that just that it's an integer.